# Need to retrieve last record with group by

Tags: mysql

I am trying to retrieve last record with group by

```
SELECT ticket_id,unique_id,subject,date,time,
                                     category,message,signature,status,username,
                                     screenshot 
                                 FROM ticket 
                                 group by unique_id
```

Result shows group based on unique_id but shows only first record not the last one. Tried `Max(ticket_id)` too but off no use.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible with a sub-query. Try this:

```
SELECT ticket_id,unique_id,subject,date,time,category,message,signature,status,username,screenshot
FROM ticket,
    (
        SELECT MAX(ticket_id) AS max_ticket_id
        FROM ticket
        GROUP BY unique_id
    ) subQuery
WHERE ticket.ticket_id = subQuery.max_ticket_id
```

Comment: It will work if there is only one group. where as i have multiple groups. showing only one record will not work

Comment: you can't control which of the group's rows will be "returned", and in newer MySQL versions the ability to SELECT columns that are not aggregated-by in a GROUP BY query is even disabled by default (it has to be explicitly enabled in the configuration).

Comment: @QadirIT i updated my answer to use a sub-query. does this work for you?

Comment: Note that we stopped writing queries this way circa 1992

Comment: @Strawberry "this way" how? with `WHERE` instead of `JOIN`? i think it's simpler for beginners. if you think your version would be better then go ahead and post it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select ticket_id,unique_id,subject,date,time,
                                 category,message,signature,status,username,
                                 screenshot 
                             FROM ticket 
                             group by unique_id order by unique_id desc limit 1;
```

Comment: Absolutely do not try this.

Comment: @Strawberry Please enlighten me with correct method.